# Why is ram usage different when creating same accounts?

Tags: accounts, ram, create

I am trying to understand why ram usage is different for the same task.

I executed

```
cleos system newaccount --stake-net "0.0010 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.0010 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 3
```

It succeeded but the creator account ram usage went up by 0.3 KiB on the first account creation, the second time I tried to create another account with the same command and parameters, creator ram usage went up only by 0.1 KiB.

Why is it different? I thought I would be charged 3 KiB everytime, since I specified 3KiB? (I know standard is 8)

Answer (score 1):

I've done some testing and apparently it is because the first time you create an account, it will also buy RAM for the first time if you haven't bought manually before, and that will create some DB entries that will use up some RAM of the creator account. Same thing happens with the bandwidth delegation part of creating a new account (which is optional, by the way).